# Regular expression to validate current DoD Password Standards

Tags: javascript, regex

Here are two different ones that are not working yet.

One:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\{\}:;,.?\-=+|<>!@#$%^&()\[\]\/\\)]{15,}
```

Two:

```
(?=^.{15,}$)(?=.*\d{2,})(?=.*\W+)(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z]{2,})(?=.*[a-z]{2,}).*$
```

**Rules:**
Passwords must be at least 15 characters in length.
Passwords must contain at least 2 character(s) from each of these 4 categories:

- uppercase alphabetical `A-Z`
- lowercase alphabetical `a-z`
- numeric `0-9`
- special characters `{}:;,.?-=+|<>!@#$%^&()[]/\`

Passwords must not contain any spaces.

Thanks for any help.

---- Edited ----

Some Samples to try

`2wsx@WSX3edc#EDC`

`3edc#EDC4rfv$RFV`

`nhy6NHY^mju7MJU&`

`1qaz!QAZ2wsx@WSX`

I have tested them at http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/ and I am not getting them to work.

I feel like some of the below examples should work but they don't or I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: **Why** can't they contain spaces? What about other special characters?

Comment: You're trying to do this with one über regular expression, why? It would be easier to code and easier to read if you tested each condition separately.

Comment: not to disaprove of the effort, but wouldnt it be good enough to just have more then 15 characters? for a lenght of 15 it hardly matters if you use words or punctuation or numbers

Comment: @Ben: No, because if he has to write something to match DoD standards, then whatever he writes had better damn well match those standards. You can't get handed a standard and then half-ass it.

Comment: What language the RX? You should always specify the language.

Comment: @Nathan It's useless you tell it to me. You should edit the post and add it to the tags. And I hope you aren't really doing the checks Client-Side only... Because even a trained monkey can skip a Javascript check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either check these regexes in one after another or create one big look-ahead-based expression from them.

**Rules:**

- *Passwords must be at least 15 characters in length.*

```
^.{15,}$
```

*Passwords must contain at least 2 character(s) from each of these 4 categories:*

- *uppercase alphabetical (A-Z)*

```
^(.*?[A-Z]){2}
```

- *lowercase alphabetical (a-z)*

```
^(.*?[a-z]){2}
```

- *numeric (0-9)*

```
^(.*?[0-9]){2}
```

- *special characters (`{}:;,.?-=+|<>!@#$%^&()[]/`)*

```
^(.*?[{}:;,.?\-=+|!@#$%^&()\[\]/]){2}
```

*Passwords must not contain any spaces.*

Why? But if you *must*, change the first expression to

```
^\S{15,}$
```

Answer (score 3):

Why do it all in one regex? Do something like:

```
if( length($password) >= 15 &&
    ($password =~ y/A-Z//) >= 2 &&
    ($password =~ y/a-z//) >= 2 &&
    ($password =~ y/0-9//) >= 2 &&
    ($password =~ y/{}:;,.?\-=+|<>!@#%^&()\[\]///) >= 2 &&
    $password =~ /^\S+$/ ) {

  print "password validates!\n";
} else {
  print "password doesn't validate!\n";
}
```

This way when you have to add more criteria, it's easy to do. This is also a hell of a lot more readable and maintainable than putting it all in one giant regex.

Comment: They don’t have to be two consecutively. Try `($password =~ y/A-Z//) >= 2` etc.

Answer (score 0):

`^(?!.* )(?=.{15})(?=.*[A-Z].*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z].*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9].*[0-9])(?=.*[{}:;,.?\-=+|<>!@#$%\^&()[\]/\\].*[{}:;,.?\-=+|<>!@#$%\^&()[\]/\\])`

My Regex should work even for separated chars. So for example **Ab0%Ab0%0000000000000** (you see, there isn't an `AA`, the two `A` are separated). I have escape the minimum number of characters (only `^` and `]`)

- `^ Beginning of the string`
- `(?!.* ) Not (any character repeated * times followed by a space)`
- `(?=.{15}) Any character for 15 times (as it's written, even if there are other characters after the 15th it won't change anything)`
- `(?=.*[A-Z].*[A-Z]) Any character repeated * times, an Upper Case letter, any character repeated * times, an Upper Case letter`
- `(?=.*[a-z].*[a-z]) Any character repeated * times, a Lower Case letter, any character repeated * times, a Lower Case letter`
- `(?=.*[0-9].*[0-9]) Any character repeated * times, a Digit, any character repeated * times, a Digit`
- `(?=.*[{}:;,.?\-=+|<>!@#$%\^&()[\]/\\].*[{}:;,.?\-=+|<>!@#$%\^&()[\]/\\]) Any character repeated * times, a Symbol, any character repeated * times, a Symbol`

All the subexpression are zero-width look-ahead (or zero-width negative look-ahead) and they start all at the first character, so they are all in "and" and they must be all true.

Comment: This demonstrates how idiotic it is to encode things as single regexes that should logically be several simple things.

Comment: @tchrist He wants to have TWO problems? They'll be HIS TWO problems! (you know, the quote about Regexes and Problems :-) )

Comment: I know the quote, but Jamie can be a dork at times.

Comment: @tchrist The thing that always baffled me is that I programmed for 15 years (more in reality) and I was happy without RE (I learned them only a year ago)... But here on SO it seems that all the Junior Programmers need to solve ALL the problems with RE... Without even knowing them! :-)

Comment: @xanatos: I was, let's say, blissfully unaware without REs.  :)  I was happy to do my searches and substrings and all that.  And when i first saw REs, i was kinda like...this looks too complicated to be useful.  But they kinda grow on ya.  Now, they're an important tool.  Paticularly since Perl (and PCRE) kinda standardized them.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.... for JavaScript... Thanks for all the help.

This one works.

```
^((?=(.*[\d]){2,})(?=(.*[a-z]){2,})(?=(.*[A-Z]){2,})(?=(.*[^\w\d\s]){2,})).{15,}$
```

Comment: That allows spaces, and it doesn't require two of the special characters you listed--just two of anything that's not `[A-Za-z0-9_]` or whitespace.  It's also vulnerable to a well-known [bug in IE's regex support](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/exec-bugs).  I suggest you go with @Tomalak's answer.

Comment: Your regex will match `1qazèQAZ2wsxèWSX`